# Bootstrap 3 problems with bold, strange formatting with .radio-inline suggested in documentation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Examples and more detail and code available here: http://bootply.com/109675

Bootstrap 3 documentation suggests this as format for radio button and suggests simply changing .radio to .radio-inline.

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
     <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="" type="radio">
Short one
     </label>
 </div>
```

Doing so seems to make the radio buttons bold.  In Chrome, the radio buttons are also significantly higher than the label.  I found this solution on bootply (http://bootply.com/102908) which kills the DIV tags and moves the .radio-inline to the LABEL tag.  It works, but not in documentation.  Is this kosher?  Another way?  Thanks.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked="" type="radio">
     Short one
</label>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to make it not bold?  You could add a CSS rule to add back the normal font-weight.

Comment: @user3185972 what you did in #3 and #4 work just fine.

Comment: @Sneaky: I think the bold after adding .radio-inline is unintended by bootstrap 3 and I'm trying to see if there is a work around or fix.

Comment: @grim  Thanks.  I know it works, I'm just wondering if there is a documented, "Bootstrap-approved" way to make it work or patch or fix.  Seems like it should work the way the documentation suggests.

Comment: Damn.  User error.  :)  I just read the docs more closely.  You **are** supposed to move the .radio-line class to the label tag.  I misread.  In my defense, it does seem a bit odd.  :)  I don't know if I can close this thread myself.